# mysql update statement gives me an error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update multiple columns at once:

```
  $query="UPDATE search_page
     SET search_page_description='".$search_page_description."',
     SET title='".$title."',
     SET h1='".$h1."',
     SET meta_description='".$metadata."'
     WHERE features_id=".$id;
     $result_update_query=databaseConn :: dbDelta($query);
```

I get this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET title='fasdf', SET h1='fasdfas', SET meta_description='fas' at line 3
```

Where does my code go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You only need one `SET` keyword

```
 $query="UPDATE search_page
     SET search_page_description='".$search_page_description."',
     title='".$title."',
     h1='".$h1."',
     meta_description='".$metadata."'
     WHERE features_id=".$id;
     $result_update_query=databaseConn :: dbDelta($query);
```

See ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

The error says line 3 thus:

> "SET title='".$title."',"

The problem is that this line contains a 'SET' keyword that is not expected.

```
 $query="UPDATE search_page
 SET search_page_description='".$search_page_description."',
 title='".$title."',
 h1='".$h1."',
 meta_description='".$metadata."'
 WHERE features_id=".$id;
 $result_update_query=databaseConn :: dbDelta($query);
```

See [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) or try [SQL UPDATE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
>   $query="UPDATE search_page
>      SET search_page_description='".$search_page_description."',
>      title='".$title."',
>      h1='".$h1."',
>      meta_description='".$metadata."'
>      WHERE features_id=".$id;
>      $result_update_query=databaseConn :: dbDelta($query);
```